# Paging library alpha version for jetpack compose. Can this alpha version be used in production?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Paging library alpha version for jetpack compose. Can this alpha version be used in production?
I have an app and I want to use pagination so I did a search on Paging

Comment: It's not restricted to use alpha versions of libraries in production. If you're ok with how it works - you can use it. Alpha in this case means that API can be changed much more often that in case of stable versions, so you may need to update your code more often too.

Comment: We are using it in production in app with 500K DAU, works well.